# Update query for the given case in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nlp

```
{ "_id" :,
   "final_terms" : [
        {
            "np" : "the role",
            "tf" : 28571.000,
            "idf" : 0
        }]
}
```

How to update and set the flag to 1 for top 30% sorted in decreasing order by final_terms.idf and 0 for the rest

```
{ "_id" :,
   "final_terms" : [
        {
            "np" : "the role",
            "tf" : 28571.000,
            "idf" : 0
            "flag": 0
        }]

}
```

I am new to mongodb, and I need to do this for nlp, the mongodb docs are less detail oriented and it is difficult get a grip on mongodb using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in steps. Firstly, you need to know how many documents will be in your result set, so that you can figure out what the top 30% is. Secondly, you do a query that will sort the documents in decreasing order by `final_terms.idf` and figure out what the value of `final_terms.idf` is for the last document in the top 30% of the result set. Once you know that, you can update all documents with a `final_terms.idf` value greater than or equal to that with `flag: 1` and all others with `flag: 0`. The exact implementation would depend on your programming language, but an implementation in the `mongo` shell would look as follows:

```
// Get count
> db.collection.find().count();
100
```

Now you know that you have 100 documents, so the top 30% will be the first 30 documents. Skip the first 29 in the sorted results and find the value for the 30th document:

```
// Sort and get value for 30th document
> db.collection.find({}, { "final_terms.idf" : 1, "_id" : 0} ).sort({ "final_terms.idf" : -1 }).skip(29).limit(1);
{ "final_terms" : { "idf" : "<SOME_VALUE>" } }
```

You now have the value at the bottom limit of the first 30%. Use that value to do the respective updates:

```
// Update top 30%
db.collection.update({ "final_terms.idf" : { $gte : <SOME_VALUE> }}, { $set : { "final_terms.flag" : 1 } }, { "multi" : true });

// Update bottom 70%
db.collection.update({ "final_terms.idf" : { $lt : <SOME_VALUE> }}, { $set : { "final_terms.flag" : 0 } }, { "multi" : true });
```

That should give you an idea of how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, can you suggest e some good reference to learn mongodb something besides the official docs.

Comment: That's great! Absolutely. I would first check out the free courses offered by [MongoDB University](http://education.mongodb.org). Also, the best book out there is Kristina Chodorow's "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide" (Second Edition).